# 3d matrix by column vector multiplication

Tags: matlab, multiplication

I have a 3d (or in general n-dimensional) matrix `A` with dimensions

```
size(A) = [d1 d2 d3 ... dn].
```

Now I want to do a vector multiplication with a column vector `v` over one of the dimensions (as I would do in 2 dimensions, where I get a vector returned - for instance for `d1 = 2`, `d3 = 4` and `size(v) = d2`), so that

```
(A*d)_i = sum(a_ij*v_j).
```

Hence I want to reduce by one dimension.

Is there a Matlab function(other than looping) that returns for a `d3`-dimensional column vector v

```
(A*v)_ij = sum(A_ijk*v_k).
```

I hope this was clear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with a few `reshape`'s:

```
A=rand(2,3,4);
v=rand(1,4);
reshape(reshape(A,[size(A,1)*size(A,2),size(A,3)])*v,[size(A,1) size(A,2)])
```

Basically, you reshape A into a 2D matrix A2((ij),(k))=A((i),(j),(k)):

```
A2=reshape(A,[size(A,1)*size(A,2),size(A,3)])
```

Then you do the usual multiplcation:

for all (ij) B2((ij))=sum_k A2((ij),(k))*v((k)):

```
B2=A2*v
```

The you reshape back:

B((i),(j))=B((ij))

```
B=reshape(B2,[size(A,1) size(A,2)])
```

I hope this is clear

Comment: alright - thanks a lot. I was hoping for something smoother, but this is fair enough, I guess.

Comment: This method only works when the dimension to be multiplied is the last dimension of the N-d matrix. It would be nice if the code worked for any dimension 1...N of the N-D matrix. Seems do-able with `dimshift` at the start and end.

Comment: It seems doable with `permute` indeed.... It would takes a few minutes to think about it. Feel free to edit my answer, or to add your own one. I have a deadline soon.

Comment: @cjh Post your example as an answer, please; it could be useful to many.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it a bit smoother. for matrices `reshape` only requires 1 argument, the other one is figured out automatically if not specified, which is very useful in exactly such situations.

So, the solution presented by Oli can be more briefly written as

```
A = rand(2,3,4);
v = rand(4,1);

A2 = reshape(A, [], numel(v));      % flatten first two dimensions
B2 = A2*v;
B  = reshape(B2, size(A, 1), []);
```